# Windows 10 machine issues, instability, unreliable test results

Tags: windows-10, file-corruption, sfc

I have two HP Elitebook 8540w machines. With the main machine (machine I use every day) if I run `sfc /scannow` it returns

```
Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.
For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at
windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For offline
repairs, details are included in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag.

The system file repair changes will take effect after the next reboot.
```

But when the drive is booted up in the alternate machine (another identical laptop that has been shelved) and booted up the scan comes out fine. I have run the deep memory checks that have all come up fine in the main machine, where is the issue? Is it for sure a hardware problem with the laptop?

Comment: When you say "main" and "alternate", do you mean you've got two drives in a RAID mirroring, or is one a physical machine, and the other virtual, over a RAID?

Comment: No I mean I have too identical pieces of hardware, two laptops. When I swap the drive from one machine to another, the behaviour changes.

Comment: to see a report for SFC, open admin cmd prompt and type: findstr /i /c:"[SR]" "%windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log" | findstr /i /v /c:"verify" > "%userprofile%\Desktop\sfc.txt"

Comment: @JW0914 unfortunately all of those steps have already failed. `/restorehealth` fails to fix anything because it can't find files and I've done everything to seed it with files from the iso. sfc /scannow fails every time. But `sfc` and `dism` both show no errors when the system drive is hosted in the alternate laptop.

Comment: @JCollins: how strictly identical are your two laptops? Do they share the exact same specs in terms of RAM quality (same brand, etc...), the same power unit? Do their BIOS/UEFI run the exact same brand and model, and fully up-to-date?

Comment: Not so, if on one PC, Windows requires, and loads in memory, a certain driver that the other unit doesn't agree with. A mere difference in components could lead to that kind of issue.

Comment: @Didier their serial numbers are only a few hundred units apart, acquired at the same time. Same model and part numbers. Same spec Crucual memory in same quantity. Same CPU and same GPU. Different SSD spec however for the system drive being moved.

Comment: @Didier I think you may have a fundamental misunderstanding as to what the error is conveying... `SFC` is discovering a hash mismatch between a system file & it's known good backup in the Component Store. `SFC` relies upon the Component Store [`%WinDir%\WinSxS`] to verify the hashes of all system files against _(among other things, the Component Store maintains a backup of all Windows system files)_. `/StartComponentCleanup` cleans up `WinSxS`, as it becomes dirty over time from updates, which will cause `/RestoreHealth` to fail and is why the command sequence I listed above must be followed.

Comment: _Cont'd_ @JCollins There's little point to running `SFC` if the Component Store has not first been checked for corruption, as if corruption does exist, `SFC` will replace system files with the corrupted versions from the Component Store.  If you don't have internet access, you'll either need to use the Windows install ISO _for the version of Windows 10 (v1903, v1909, etc.) currently installed_ or by using the `%WinDir%\WinSxS` directory from another PC, with the same Windows version, by specifying the `/Source` parameter.  I'll provide the steps in a reply if you don't have internet access.

Comment: I have internet access. However standby, I have started using an alternate memory diagnostic (from Ubuntu), and the whole root cause could be one bad memory stick.

Comment: @JW0914 the test is definitely showing one particular stick with errors. I have already relentlessly tried the `/restorehealth` using the `/source` from the `install.wim` extracted from the `install.esd` file of `index = 6` corresponding to my Professional x64 version of Windows. The source files are never found and `dism` always fails.

Comment: (And I thought it *couldn't* be hardware-related... I might just fry some popcorn, this is gonna be good...)

Comment: @JCollins A bad RAM DIMM is not causing the issue... Correlation does not equal causation, but if you believe otherwise, replace it and the error will continue.  You have the same fundamental misunderstanding of what's occurring as Didier.  Your `DISM` commands are failing because you're not doing it correctly, but hey what do I know... You can't help folks who refuse to listen.  Best of luck _(you may want to try reading Microsoft Docs, as perhaps reading this same information from Microsoft will make you realize your fundamental misunderstanding, as my patience has come to an end)_.

Comment: `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` > `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` > Reboot > `SFC /ScanNow` > Reboot.  Explanation of these three commands can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1539273/windows-10-machine-issues-instability-unreliable-test-results?noredirect=1#comment2337688_1539273) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1539273/windows-10-machine-issues-instability-unreliable-test-results?noredirect=1#comment2337695_1539273), as I've deleted all other comments since I'm done repeating myself.

Comment: @JW0914 with the DIMM removed I have managed to have dism /.. /restorehealth complete successfully and sfc /scannow both give good answers. I hate to say it but I think there *were* some corrupted system files, but the system didn't seem to have a chance of fixing them without sorting this out first. Thanks for your help, it's nice to get enthusiastic folk such as yourself involved in troubleshooting.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: @JCollins It would be interesting to see what files were found to be corrupt in the `CBS.log` and `DISM.log`... if you post the logs to PasteBin, I can reply back w/ what lines can be added to a code box in your question, as a RAM DIMM shouldn't cause this issue since the files being checked aren't loaded into RAM; their hashes are simply checked against known good backups within `.cab` files in `%WinDir%\WinSxS`.  I will likely end up writing a community wiki for those three commands, as I'm having to comment on questions w/ them once a week or so on average, which adds to my lack of patience

Comment: @JW0914 What are the security risks, if any, of sharing logs such as these?

Comment: @JCollins AFAIK, there are none.  `%WinDir%\Logs\DISM\dism.log` will often contain user names in the form of the `%LocalAppData%\Temp` path.  If you have concerns, open each in a text editor, such as VS Code, and scroll through them, as they're system image servicing logs.  The only relevant info in each will be during the time frame that you ran `SFC` and `DISM`, and all that I'll be doing is doing a backward word search for "_error_" and "_warning_", which is something you can do, pasting those lines into a code box.

Answer (score 0):

Issue appears to be caused by bad memory. Hypothesis is that the corrupt files were not corrupt, but an illusion caused by bad memory. This would explain why the corruption is not seen on the other machine. Note for future readers: The HP BIOS memory tester did not find this error, the Ubuntu Memtest did.

[image]

After removing the suspect DIMM, the Windows maintenance commands began to succeed.

[image]

Comment: Glad you cleared that up. If I may venture a thought: I know you must have chosen this setup for a reason, but sharing a hard drive between two machines, however close to identical they may seem, is a risky proposition. You could find a way to synch the content of two hard drives in your two PCs over the network, or any other way, and save yourself a lot of pain, but again, I'm sure you have your reasons. Really glad it worked out for you.

Comment: @Didier This was entirely a diagnostic choice: would the faults follow the drive or stay with the remaining hardware? I was just fortunate to have an identical laptop with which to test. With regards memory I have tested it a few times since issues started, today is the first day any issues started reporting.

Comment: Like I said, you had your reasons, and I respect that. We're not going to discuss good practice here, but as you've stated: although you tested your RAM several times, it reported all good until it didn't. What I said in a comment earlier still stands, at least to my understanding: a hard drive with a functioning copy of Windows that you transfer onto another PC, and that starts misbehaving, usually smells like hardware-*related* problems. Maybe not a faulty component per se, but it must have to do with how the OS interracts with its new hardware environment.

Comment: In my experience, even as far back as Win98, putting a drive in a donor machine just hmgot it exciting about all the new hardware it could install drivers for. I can see problems perhaps in this case if there are only subtle differences and the OS doesn't twig that a change is required and could cause some strange effects. In this case it wasnt the switch that initiated the problem but actually the opposite, it performed better in the donor machine. Thanks for your input on it.

Comment: @JCollins Windows has never supported hot-swapping OS drives between machines, as it will cause instability over time due to the incorrect machine ID, hardware IDs, OEM and CPU drivers _(CPU drivers must be installed immediately following OOBE and **before** any other drivers, software, or Windows Updates - simply uninstalling the old Chipset and IMEI drivers, then installing the new ones, will not work)_.  Additionally, hot-swapping a Win10 HDD will result in an unlicensed install upon running Windows Update since the Win10 license is tied to the motherboard's hardware ID.